# Можно ли использовать отрицательные пиксели

Tags: html, css

Верстаю сайт, нужно подвинуть элемент, но это можно сделать только посредством **-328px**;
Так вот собственно вопрос, можно-ли так делать? Не противоречит ли это стандартам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартам не противоречит. Однако наводит на мысль, что может быть лучше будет использовать другую структуру разметки ( использовать position или float ).